# Unable to delete a document in mongodb using DELETE method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to node and mongodb, I have created a embedded/nested document, when I am trying to delete it using router.delete method its resulting in the following error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify (). How to fix this and delete my document?

I tried with both findByIdAndRemove and findByIdAndDelete of the mongodb method.

```
**Article Schema**
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    articleName: {
        type: String
    },
    author: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    }],
    comments: [commentSchema]
})

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)

**Route Delete Method**
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const article = Article.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.send(article)
})

**Comment Schema**
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    articles: {
        type: new mongoose.Schema({
            articleName: {
                type: String
            },
            author: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Author'
            }],
        })
    },
    users: {
        type: new  mongoose.Schema({
            name: String
        })
    },
    comment: String
})

**User Schema**
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String, email: String})
```

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular `structure to JSON at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)`

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing `await`

```
**Route Delete Method**
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const article = await Article.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.send(article)
})
```